# How can I get Electron stdout content from within my main process code?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, electron

Can I somehow get the content of stdout from Electron, from within my main process code?

So, for example, I have an electron app, and in my main process code:

```js
import {app, BrowserWindow, globalShortcut, session} from "electron"

// Now what? How do I get any and all output that goes to the console?
```

The reason I am curious is because, when I set some flags for Chrome by using `app.commandLine.appendSwitch(...)`, I see output in the console from Chrome, and I'd like to see if it is possible to get this output somehow, from within my Electron main process code.

EDIT, in case the above wasn't clear enough:

Electron outputs to console. My code is running in Electron. The underlying Chrome instance, for example, outputs information to stdout, so *my own electron application* therefore outputs to stdout the same stuff that the underlying Chrome outputs.

I'd like to capture all put from *my own electron application* using the code within my own electron application.

Does that make sense?

For example, if I put the following in my Electron main process code:

```js
app.commandLine.appendSwitch('remote-debugging-port', '8315')
```

this causes my Electron application to output stuff to stdout (or similar, as I see it in the terminal output).

I'd like to capture this output from the same code that causes the output, so:

```js
// this line indirectly causes my app to output to stdout
// (because it is forwarding Chrome's output, or something):
app.commandLine.appendSwitch('remote-debugging-port', '8315')

// Now how to I capture that output?
```

Comment: I didn't figure out how to get stdout, but I did figure how to find the debugger websocket URL at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55579075/55580078#55580078

Answer (score -1):

Yes! You certainly can. Electron works natively with the machine you're running it on, so long as your security allows it.

```
const buffer_size = (1024 * 500000);//Very large buffer size. Shouldn't ever need anything this big

     getCommandLineResponse: async function (callback) {
            let date = moment().toDate();

            let promise = function () {
                return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                    //create a child process to run
                    var {exec} = require('child_process');
                    let path = require('path');
                    let app = require('electron').remote;
                    let exePath = "YOUREXE.exe";
                    //Define the command line interface and all arguments
                    let cli = `"${exePath}"`;
                    //This is the core. Call the .EXE specifying the options
                    exec(cli, {maxBuffer: buffer_size}, (err, stdout, stderr) => {
                        if (err) {
                            reject(stderr);
                        } else {
                            console.log('Received from CLI - ' + stdout);
                            resolve(stdout);
                        }

                        exec = null;
                    });

                });
            };

            //Execute the CLI
            await promise(filePath);

            if(callback)
            {
                await callback();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Hi Jacob, thanks for answering! I don't think I explained well enough what I meant, so I updated the question.