# nodeJS - Communicate with an electron app running in the background through a CLI

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, command-line-interface

as an example of what I'm trying to achieve, consider launching VS Code from the terminal. The `code <file-name>` command opens an instance of vs code if not only running, or tells it to open a file otherwise. Also, once opened, the user can use the terminal session for other tasks again (as if the process was disowned).

My script needs to interact with my electron app in the same way, with the only difference being that my app will be in the tray and not visible in the dock.
.
The solution only needs to work on linux

Comment: Try redirecting the std:in and std:out of your electron app to the script you are running as in this example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55579168/how-can-i-get-electron-stdout-content-from-within-my-main-process-code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a unix socket server for inter-process-communication.

In electron

```
const handleIpc = (conn) => {
  conn.setEncoding('utf8');
  conn.on('data',(line) => {
    let args = line.split(' ');
    switch(args[0]) {
      case 'hey': 
        conn.write('whatsup\n');
        break;
      default: conn.write('new phone who this?\n');
    }
    conn.end();
  })
}
const server = net.createServer(handleIpc);
server.listen('/tmp/my-app.sock');
```

Then your CLI is:

```
#!/usr/bin/node
const net = require('net');
let args = process.argv;
args.shift(); // Drop /usr/bin/node 
args.shift(); // Drop script path

let line = args.join(' ');
net.connect('/tmp/my-app.sock',(conn)=>{
  conn.setEncoding('utf8');
  conn.on('data',(response)=>{
    console.log(response);
    process.exit(0);
  });
  conn.write(line+'\n');
}).on('error',(err)=>{
  console.error(err);
  process.exit(1);
});
```

Comment: Second script fails when script is launched using `./script.js args` (after `chmod +x script.js`) instead of `node script.js args` because it shifts first 2 arguments, but second argument can be an actually argument

Comment: First argument is always the path to the executable, which is node no matter how you launch it

Comment: And by "no matter how you launch it" I mean by convention and how you're describing launching it. Technically you can mangle argv if you explicitly made the system call from another program.

Comment: Yes, but with NodeJS script argv usually can be A) `['/usr/bin/node', 'filename.js', 'arg1', 'arg2']` B) `['./filename.js', 'arg1', 'arg2']`. In case B second argument matters too (but it is `.shift()`ed)

Comment: I don't know of any situation on linux where it can be B. You can explicitly set argv if you're making a system call but even then when the node executable looks for the script to run at argv[1] it will fail.

Comment: As described in `man exec`: `The const char *arg and subsequent ellipses can be thought of as arg0, arg1, ..., argn.  Together they describe a list of one or more pointers to null-terminated strings that represent the  argument list  available to the executed program.  The first argument, by convention, should point to the filename associated with the file being executed. `

Comment: Just try it. Make a script that does nothing but `console.log(process.argv)`, you'll never see B

Comment: I tried it. Sorry, I was wrong. It can be B only with Python (I thought Linux handles "shebang" `#!` same, so argued for this). Your code is 100% correct.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you want to keep only one instance of your app and to handle attempts to launch another instance. In old versions of Electron, [`app.makeSingleInstance(callback)`](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/v0.36.10/docs/api/app.md#appmakesingleinstancecallback) was used to achieve this. As for Electron ...v13 - v15, [`app.requestSingleInstanceLock()`](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/v13.1.4/docs/api/app.md#apprequestsingleinstancelock) with `second-instance` event is used. Here is an example how to use it:

```
const { app } = require('electron');
let myWindow = null;

const gotTheLock = app.requestSingleInstanceLock();

if (!gotTheLock) {
    app.quit();
} else {
    app.on('second-instance', (event, commandLine, workingDirectory) => {
        // Someone tried to run a second instance
        // Do the stuff, for example, focus the window
        if (myWindow) {
            if (myWindow.isMinimized()) myWindow.restore()
            myWindow.focus()
        }
    })

    // Create myWindow, load the rest of the app, etc...
    app.whenReady().then(() => {
        myWindow = createWindow();
    })
}
```

So when someone will launch `./app arg1 arg2` at the second time, the callback will be called. By the way, this solution is cross-platform.